# MSSQL started working very slow without any reason

Tags: sql-server, performance, updates

Maybe after some updates in windows 10 , MSSQL server started work very slow an not turning on, on windows start, I think maybe some windows defender delay/issue but after turning off windows defender nothing changes.

Does anyone have same issue, when mssql starting work very bad with no reason.

Running windows 10 64bit, visual studio 2015, and generally PC started to work slow, startup, logon.

System Configuration

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.14393 Build 14393
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name DESKTOP-BUC72J8
System Manufacturer Acer
System Model    TravelMate 5760G
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  HuronRiver_CRB
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2501 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   INSYDE V1.18, 10/17/2011
SMBIOS Version  2.7
Embedded Controller Version 255.255
BIOS Mode   Legacy
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Acer
BaseBoard Model Not Available
BaseBoard Name  Base Board
Platform Role   Mobile
Secure Boot State   Unsupported
PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible
Windows Directory   C:\WINDOWS
System Directory    C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale  United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.14393.0"
User Name   DESKTOP-BUC72J8\prime
Time Zone   Caucasus Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 8.00 GB
Total Physical Memory   7.85 GB
Available Physical Memory   3.14 GB
Total Virtual Memory    9.10 GB
Available Virtual Memory    3.73 GB
Page File Space 1.25 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.
```

***UPDATE***

LOCALHOST is not responding, issue from EDGE, after clicking on button to get data from table with query.

Comment: Post your system configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with windows update SQL-wasn't work correctly.
After format everything works clear.

Answer (score 0):

You might look to tag this in the windows groups as well, but when I have these issues I look first at what other programs and services I have running, using the task manager as a start.

Most recently I have suffered a similar slow down, and it was the Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool that was the cause, I let it continue until it had finished (consuming some 50% of CPU !) and all was well again.

Comment: I have very strange issue, site works, but no data comes to web from db, everything was working yesterday, and with no reason MSSQL started not to work, how can I check what program block mssql to work with my site, connectionstring and everything else are correct.